# Take a Publishing Page "Offline"

Tags: publishing-site, publishing-page

Is there a way to take a Published Publishing Page offline such that it isn't accessible to anonymous users of a WCM website?

If you un-publish, the page's most recent version will still be accessible.

I'd rather avoid breaking permission inheritance of possible.

Another option is to have an 'archive' library with the page content types associated, and move the page there.

SharePoint Server 2010, by the way.

Anyone figured out any other way?

EDIT: In my particular example, I just noticed there was only one page in the sub site, so it made sense just to revoke anonymous access for that subsite. But I would still like to know how to do this for a page, if it all possible without breaking permissions inheritance.

Comment: can't you play with publishing dates ?

Comment: Are you sure this is correct (or am I missing something)? I did some testing with OOTB Article Page in Pages library (version on, check in/out, approval on and off, anonymous access set to View Items ). I have created several major versions of Article Page. When I used OOTB `Unpublish this version` anonymous user couldn't see Article Page anymore.

Comment: Unpublish will definitely make the page not visible for anonymous users.

Comment: But won't it keep the most recent major version in the history? Let me try it now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steve B, this is my experience as well.

Unpublish should do the trick.

Comment: Ok that worked, but defies logic. The previous Major version remains in the document's history, but remains inaccessible to anonymous users?